# Understanding a pointer function that returns a pointer to an array

Tags: c, pointers, function-pointers

So, I am just trying to wrap my head around "pointer function that returns a pointer to an array"... but to start off slowly, I had to understand this:

```
void Print(const char c){
    printf("\nPrint: %c\n", c);
}

int main () {
    void (*FunctionPointer)(const char);
    FunctionPointer = &Print;
    FunctionPointer('a');
}
```

Which I do - pretty easy to guess what is going on... FunctionPointer just points to the location where the Print function "resides". Instead of jumping to a specific memory address (stored on a register) of a specific function, I can now be more flexible and point to any function that I want to access.

But I am stuck with the following...

```
int main () {
    int (*FunctionPointer())[];
}
```

Now it seems that the function that is pointed by FunctionPointer, can in fact return a pointer to an array of type int. The compiler accepts the second line - so far so good - and I also understand the concept... but I am getting stuck regarding the implementation.

FunctionPointer needs - once again, to point to a function. That function can indeed return a pointer that points to an array of type int... soooooo:

```
int *Array(){
    int ar[2] = {5,6};
    return ar;
}

int main () {
    int (*FunctionPointer())[];
    FunctionPointer = &Array;
}
```

However, the last piece of code is just not accepted by the compiler.... So, what gives?

Comment: You are returning a dangling pointer.

Comment: (1) `Array` returns a pointer to a local variable. Once the function returns, such pointer is unusable. (2) `Function` is a [pointer to a function that returns a pointer to an array of `int`](https://cdecl.org/?q=int+%28*FunctionPointer%28%29%29%5B%5D). `Array` is a [function that returns a pointer to an `int`](https://cdecl.org/?q=int+*Array%28%29). These things are incompatible. (3) For a function that does not accept arguments, use `(void)` parameter list. `()` means the number of parameters and their type is unspecified. This is not what you want.

Comment: Ok, that clears things up... So, if I want to Array to return a pointer to an array of int... how would one do that? (Thank you for the reply)

Comment: For a function to return a pointer to something, that something needs to outlive the function call. So it cannot be a local automatic variable. It can be a static variable, or it can be a global variable, or it can be a block of memory allocated with `malloc` (but then you need to `free` it). I recommend reading about it in a good C book. Internet forums will not take you very far.

Comment: I am actually trying to make sense of some University textbooks. (*function())[] was just an example that was just a mention, nothing more... Just got me curious. Of course, I have experimented with C, just not that much as I wanted. I am also a bit of ashamed, since local variable declaration scope is pretty much beginner stuff, don't know why I completly ignored that part :(. Any way -  Thank you so much for your feedback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With

```
int (*FunctionPointer())[];
```

you've declared `FunctionPointer` as a *function* returning a pointer to an array of int -- not a function pointer.  You want

```
int *(*FunctionPointer)();
```

If you use `[]` here, you'll get an error, as functions can't return arrays -- arrays are not first class types -- and unlike with function parameters, arrays will not be silently converted to pointers when used as the return value of a function type.  With that, you'll still get the warning

```
t.c:3:12: warning: function returns address of local variable [-Wreturn-local-addr]
     return ar;
            ^~
```

which is pretty self-explanatory

Comment: These answers really helped me understand C more. So, lets say I have the first case... How do I assign to it (since I can't return an array pointer from a function).

Comment: The first case, you can't assign to, as it is a function, not a pointer at all.  You can return a pointer to an array, you just can't return an array.  If you want to return an array if effect, you usually just return a pointer (to the array's first element), as that is what an "array" type expression will decay to in a return statement (as you are doing in your `Array` function)

Comment: hmmmm I am starting to get it now. Thank you so much for your feedback.

Answer (score 0):

You have declared the array of function pointers. Arrays can't be assignable. Functions can't return arrays. You might wish

```
int* (*FunctionPointer)();
FunctionPointer = &Array;
```

Comment: Yes I was aware that you could do that. Much easier to write and understand... I was just curious. So I can't return a pointer to an array, even if the compiler allows me to declare pointer to a function that returns a pointer to an array of int? Curious

Answer (score 0):

Function pointers are much easier when you use typedefs. You can simply use the same notation as "normal" data pointers.

```
// func is a function type. It has one parater and returns pointer to int
typedef int *func(const char);

// funcptr is a pointer to func
func *funcptr;
```